# Is it possible in Ansible to generate a hashing number from a string?

Tags: ansible

In order to generate random cron executions for each host, I'd like to randomize the hour when it is going to be executed, to spread the load and avoid all hosts to run hard tasks at the same time.

So, if it would be possible to generate a different hour and minute for each host, it would spread it automatically.

Example:

```
cron:
  name: "Conquer the world"
  minute: "{{ ansible.hostname | str2num(0, 59) }}"
  hour: "{{ ansible.hostname | str2num(4, 6) }}"
  job: "conquer_the_world.sh"
```

Wanted function is what I named `str2num`, that should generate the same number for the same host in a deterministic way, and may be different for each host.

Is already there any solution for this or should I create a custom filter for this?

**ANSWER**

I finally found the answer by myself, thanks to the blog post: https://ansibledaily.com/idempotent-random-number/:

```
cron:
  name: "Conquer the world"
  minute: "{{ (59 |random(seed=ansible_hostname)) }}"
  hour: "{{ (2 |random(seed=ansible_hostname)) + 4  }}"
  job: "conquer_the_world.sh"
```

In general: `{{ ( (MAX - MIN) | random(seed=ansible_hostname)) + MIN  }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ ( inventory_hostname | hash('sha256') | int(0, 16) ) % 59 }}
```

Comment: Although, I do think `{{ 60 | random(seed=inventory_hostname) }}` achieves the same and is a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Random Number Filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#random-number-filter). There is a cron example

```yaml
"{{ 60|random }} * * * * root /script/from/cron"
# => '21 * * * * root /script/from/cron'
```

An option would be to create a "schedule" and then use it. The attribute *seed* makes the task idempotent. For example the play below

```yaml
- hosts: test_jails
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        mcs: "{{ mcs|default([])|
                 combine({item :{'my_cron_hour':(24|random(seed=item)),
                                 'my_cron_minute':(60|random(seed=item))}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ play_hosts }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: my_cron_schedule
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  mcs:
    test_11:
      my_cron_hour: 2
      my_cron_minute: 4
    test_12:
      my_cron_hour: 5
      my_cron_minute: 11
    test_13:
      my_cron_hour: 13
      my_cron_minute: 27
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. That is not deterministic and will generate different numbers in each execution.

Comment: Right. Added *seed* fixed it. Thank you for having pointed to this.